# Wordpress custom API endpoint, making arguments required not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I appreciate your help; I have wordpress 6.3x and have defined a custom endpoint as follows;

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route('fs/v1', '/fs_ski_resort/', array(
            'methods'   => 'GET',
            'callback'  => 'fs_ski_resort_data',
            'args'      =>  array(
                    'osm_geometry' => array(
                            'required' => true
                        )
                ) 
        )
    );
});
```

If I run the below, it doesn't work as expected.  I want the API to say, the `meta_value` is required for the `meta_key` but instead it returns all ski resorts.  How to I say that the meta_value is also required?

```
https://www.example.com/api/fs/v1/fs_ski_resort/?osm_geometry
```

The below works as expected and returns attributes for a single ski resort:

```
https://www.example.com/api/fs/v1/fs_ski_resort/?osm_geometry=way-1176728877
```

The below also works as expected and replies, osm_geometry is required

```
https://www.example.com/api/fs/v1/fs_ski_resort/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `validation_callback` property to check whether the param is empty.

```php
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route('fs/v1', '/fs_ski_resort/', array(
            'methods'   => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'fs_ski_resort_data',
            'args'      =>  array(
                    'osm_geometry' => array(
                            'required' => true,
                            'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                                    return !empty($param);
                            }
                        )
                ) 
        )
    );
});
```

**Update:**
It may be annoying and not a best practice if you have many APIs for which that validation should be checked.

You can extract that anonymous function into a named function and pass the function to `validation_callback`:

```php
function checkParamIsNotEmpty($param, $request, $key)
{
    return !empty($param);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route(
        'fs/v1',
        '/fs_ski_resort/',
        array(
            'methods'   => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'fs_ski_resort_data',
            'args'      =>  array(
                'osm_geometry' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'validate_callback' => 'checkParamIsNotEmpty'
                )
            )
        )
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will read more about that.  It works well.

Comment: @spreaderman
I'm glad that it was helpful. Many things like that are happening in WordPress, and you will end up with a custom callback or query.
If you aren't familiar with `sanitize_callback`, I suggest reading about that too.
Also, I've updated the answer to a better one since you may need to use this validation in multiple APIs.

Comment: That is even cleaner.  Thanks!